# Type class so that every method must be "getter"

Tags: typescript

I am interested in creating a class where every method must be a getter. Is this possible?

Valid:

```
class Example implements AllGetters {
  get alpha () {
  }
  get beta () {
  }
}
```

Invalid:

```
class Example implements AllGetters {
  get alpha () {
  }
  beta () {
  }
}
```

Comment: This example code doesn't seem to be a [mcve] since getters need to return something.  The compiler doesn't see a difference between `get foo() {return x}` and `readonly foo = x` so I doubt this can be enforced.  I mean, you could say that a class can't have any methods but that would forbid something like `get bar() {return ()=>x}` also.

Answer (score 0):

Possible using `Exclude` with a generic type:

```js
type AllGetters<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: Exclude<T[k], Function>
}

class A implements AllGetters<A> {
    // simple properties: OK
    a: string = 'foo';
    b: number = 1;

    // type error: type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    c(): number {
        return 2;
    }

    // getter: OK
    get d(): string {
        return 'hi';
    }

    // getter: not OK because it returns a function
    // type error: type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    get e(): Function {
        return console.log;
    }
}
```

Caveats:

- There is no difference in type between a simple property and a getter; you only said that all *methods* must be getters, so this should be OK for your use-case.
- A getter returning a function is also not allowed, since there is no difference in type between this and a method.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=6&pln=18&pc=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA4hYwICcDOAeAKgPigF4oBvAKCiqgG0BrKASwDso6IQB7AMylwF0AXFACiADwDGcAK4ATCHnr8ANFABi05hOCNOzfOQC+5clICGmTLCYBbMHAg2IzYFfhIUaLNhiEK1KAB6QKhMRjsHKDB0Tkh0HQhMYQB5AGlKajNhTGB0FgBzYigAcm5OTmKAbgyqACNhZmkbWowigEZqmqCQ0EgoDBj0YV7oYoAKAEpiQkbmjGKmK2ZOYCgLMPzmM1rI4E4oEZLmCAA3eYA6LolJhqaW9DIugPQUaXRWACZqgOMu4Kh8p4MCl0gFAatZDdQrkCo8As9Xu8SgALRhVLq-AL-cFeBorKBpKAtCRmaSYaCMVYvYBvZhWMxQbiabS6Zh-HrgaADThDA6ckoaLQ6PQLRhLfHrRibba7faHYrHM7oYqXMEofpQwUsvRw+FUam0qASPSYTgOc5wTj5b7UYzGIA)